# Make Chart.js not extend beyond X axis min and max

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I use Chart.js to draw an area chart.

Options of X-axis are the following:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: "time",
    gridLines: {
        color: "#DCDCDC"
    },
    time: {
        unit: "month",
        unitStepSize: 1,
        displayFormats: {
            "month": "MM.YYYY"
        }
    },
    ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
        min: minDate,
        max: maxDate,
        padding: 0,
        maxRotation: 0,
        minRotation: 0
    }
}]
```

However, Chart.js extends X-axis beyond my `min` and `max` restrictions if there is data which takes a part of another month. It "rounds" X axis to the closest full month to make a tick.

For instance, if I have January, 31 in my data, then my chart starts from January, 1. If I remove January, 31 data, then it starts from February, 1, as expected.

**`data[0]`** is January, 31; **`minData`** is January, 31:
[image]

**`data[0]`** is February, 1; **`minData`** is February, 1:
[image]

How to make it **strictly** start from `min` date? I expect it to start from January, 31 and just start to draw a tick a little to the right.

Comment: can I get some sample data to play around with, a JSFiddle or something?